# android.media Image to byte[]

Tags: android, arcore, google-vision

I'm using ArSceneView ArFrame to get the camera image

```
arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().acquireCameraImage()"
```

This returns an android.media Image model. I'm trying to convert this image to     :

```
com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.Image
```

The only way I can tell that I can do that is by converting the android.media Image to a btye[] and then using the byte[] to create the vision Image model. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to convert the android.media Image.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone ever runs into this issue. I found a solution:

Using the android.media Image model we can convert to byte[] using this -

```
byte[] data = null;
data = NV21toJPEG(
       YUV_420_888toNV21(image),
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());



private static byte[] YUV_420_888toNV21(Image image) {
    byte[] nv21;
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
    int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
    int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

    nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

    //U and V are swapped
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

    return nv21;
}


private static byte[] NV21toJPEG(byte[] nv21, int width, int height) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```